# Remotely debugging my node app that is hosted on AWS

Tags: node.js, debugging, amazon-web-services

I would like to connect to my node server running in debug mode on AWS (node --debug app.js) from my development machine, and be able to debug my app remotely.

Two questions:

- Can I do this with node-inspector? I wish I could, but node-inspector fails to install on my AWS instance.
- Any alternatives that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 44):

And with the help of [tepez's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30974089/2929465) answer, the following worked for me (Node Inspector v0.12.2):

On my machine:

```
ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 <username>@<host> -N
```

On the remote server:

```
node-debug --cli <appname>
```

And enter the following address in the browser:

```
127.0.0.1:8080/?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858
```

Comment: Thank you for showing the URL along with the SSH command.  It's too easy to get mixed up without it.  Worked great for me!

Answer (score 27):

Forward remote debugger port with ssh from your dev machine

```
ssh -L 5858:127.0.0.1:5858 ubuntu@some.ec2.host.com
```

And now you can start `node-inspector` as if the debugger is running locally.

Comment: I think this is the best option because `--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229` leaves it open for anyone unless you set up a firewall. To expand on this answer (because I didn't understand it at first myself): `ssh -L <local-port>:127.0.0.1:<remote-port> <server-ip/domain>`. You're probably already going to be using 9229 for local apps, so `local-port` will have to be something else (I chose 9339), 'remote-port' would be 9229 by default. Then you must leave the ssh connection open, go into Chrome's Node targets and add `localhost:9339` (or whatever port you chose). Voila.

Answer (score 17):

Allow me to present an alternative using `node --inspect`. I had the same need, although in a Windows environment, I believe this should work for you.

**Remote machine** (tested with Node 6.10.2, Windows Server 2012)

`node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 <appname>.js`

**Local Machine** (tested with Win 10, Chrome 60.0.3112.90)

In Chrome DevTools - Click the **vertical ellipsis menu** in top right:

1. Go to: More Tools -> Remote Devices
2. Under **Network targets** Click **Add address**
3. Enter `<remote-ip>:9229`
4. Once you enter address and remote target is connected you'll see Node.JS Icon on Top Left of DevTools
5. Click NodeJS Logo to launch DevTools Node Debugger

Screenshots of Steps 1,3,4 below.

[image: DevTools Menu]

[image: Network Targets]
[image: Remote Target Connected]

Comment: This is insecure, though, right? Is there a secure way, like to let only your home IP instead of anyone?

Comment: You can control traffic to your EC2 instance by ports via a firewall to only allow selected IPs - checkout EC2 security groups/VPCs.

Comment: I think Andrey Sidorov's answer might be an even better approach, at least for me, using SSH tunneling.

Comment: Thanks - we found this worked to attach a host-level IDE debugger to a Dockerised Node app. My assumption is that since the `0.0.0.0` is at the container level, this is effectively 127.0.0.1 on the host.

Answer (score 13):

One more option to use `0.0.0.0` to listen to request from outside:

```
node-debug --web-host=0.0.0.0 --cli app.js
```

and visit this address to debug:

```
http://<the-domain>:8080/?port=5858
```

it would be better if HTTP/2 is available since there are lots of small files.

Comment: While I wouldn't use this for anything that's publicly accessible, it works well for my dev environment running on a virtual machine.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can use `node --inspect` too in your remote machine.

1. Start your node with `node --inspect myapp.js`
2. Then locally `ssh -L 9229:127.0.0.1:9229 myuser@myserver -N`
3. Search for an string like this at the log head and copy it
   `chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@60cd6e859b9ff284980/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:9229/bef2ae68`
4. Paste it in your chrome browser

Enjoy :)

If you are using `pm2` just add this on your ecosystem.js

```
"apps": [{
    "name": "myapp",
    "script": "index.js",
    "node_args": ["--inspect"],
...
```

Answer (score 9):

Also you can specify `--web-host` argument.

```
node-inspector --web-host host.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: +1 This works perfectly when you're working inside a VM and you want to access the debugger from your host.

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me:

1. Start node-inspector on server.
2. Start debugee on remote server with `--debug` flag.
3. Note the port that the debugger listens on, i.e. `Debugger listening on port DEBUG_PORT` message.
4. Create an ssh tunnel for port `8080`, not the `DEBUG_PORT` as Andrey Sidorov's answer suggests.
5. Open `SERVER_API:8080/debug?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=DEBUG_PORT` in browser an voilà.

Node Inspector v0.10.1

Comment: for me it worked except in step 5 where what did the trick was localhost:8080/?port=DEBUG_PORT