# A Good Explanation of Remotely Debugging NodeJS on EC2

Tags: node.js, debugging, ssh, amazon-ec2

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057417/remotely-debugging-my-node-app-that-is-hosted-on-aws) post, but it's not quite clear to me.

If I want to debug my NodeJS app running on EC2 (ubuntu 12.04) from my laptop - how do I do it?

I'm running the following on EC2

```
nodemon --debug app.js
```

And I've got node-inspector installed on EC2.

When I run the ssh command, I get the following:

```
C:\>ssh -L 5858:127.0.0.1:5858 ubuntu@ubuntu-aws
The authenticity of host 'ubuntu-aws (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is ...
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'ubuntu-aws,XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

First, is that right?  I run ssh on my laptop?  Then I run node-inspector on EC2?  Then I'll be able to connect with Chrome Dev tools from laptop?

And how do I fix that ssh error?

Answer (score 0):

you still have to include your pemfile, like in your example: `ssh -i pemfile.key -L 5858:127.0.0.1:5858 ubuntu@ubuntuaws`